# Blockchain api v2: Send payment not working

Tags: php, api, blockchain

I am trying to send the btc to the user using blockchain V2 API. 
I have gone through the documentation and using the below code to send the btc to the user. But it is not being executed.

```
<?php



echo " send test<br>";
include 'db_config/connection.php';


$action = "completed";
$order_id = "12345";

$sql = "SELECT * from wallet_config";
$result= $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $guid = $row['wallet_id'];
        $main_password = $row['password'];
        $from = $row['wallet'];

      }

    $amount = 0.01 * 100000000;  // 100000000satoshi = 1 btc
    $to = "1J528hXvotieFZJkLA66g7NntXCXtNSm78";


    $json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&to=$to&amount=$amount&from=$from";

    echo $json_url;

    $json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

    $json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

    $message = $json_feed->message;
    $tx_hash = $json_feed->tx_hash;

    print_r($json_feed);


    $sql1 = "UPDATE buy_order set status ='$action', tx_id = '$tx_hash' where order_id = '$order_id'";

    $result1=$conn->query($sql1) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    if($result1){
      if(!isset($tx_hash)){
        echo "Transaction for Order id $order_id not porceeded. Try sending BTC manually.";
      }
      echo "Order id $order_id marked as $action..";
    }else{
      echo "Something went wrong... Try Again";
    }

}else{
  echo "Something went wrong... Try Checking wallet config";
}
echo "<br>last";

?>
```

The problem is that the transaction is not completed. I even tried to echo the **$json_feed** and it shows nothing.

I really do not understand why it is not working here.

When i paste the $json_url in the browser, it shows the following error

```
`<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>`
```

Comment: seems problem in `$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&to=$to&amount=$amount&from=$from";` can you access this url in browser?

Comment: @Bhaskar when i access the url in the browser, it gave the that error `<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>`

Comment: I have not read bloackchain documentation but I can tell you one thing, you should use `curl` to call this api.. and I also think that is rest bases API. Please read documentation carefully. Hope will get it done. `file_get_contents()` will not work.

Comment: I their documentation, they have not mentioned the use of curl for the api access. They simply use the `file_get_contents()`. I will try to use the curl for this one

Comment: Still not getting any result. @Bhaskar what might be the error ?

Comment: share documentation link!

Comment: @Bhaskar here is the link [Blockchain Wallet Api](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install library at your local from `https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3`? 
if not, install it firstly.

Did you create your GUID with this api call? as per your error msg, seems you did not create GUID.
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create 
check documentation for details if not created

then call payment api, your url would be your localhost url like

```
http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&fee=$fee



$json_url = "http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&fee=$fee";    
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
var_dump($json_feed);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i did use the GUID. It is the wallet identifier which is used to log into the blockchain wallet. As you can see in my code, i have fetched that code from database. That is the same code i have used in my code, but not running.

Comment: @BipInn may be your are using https://blockchain.info url, you should use your localhost or dev server url here

Comment: i have tried using localhost. But itwont even run when localhost is used as the server

Comment: I'm having the same problem... just a null response. were you able to fix this?

Comment: Hi, please I'm a bit confused as to the use of `localhost` when calling this api. Can someone please clarify exactly what this means? i.e. if I want to call this api, and I have an ubuntu or redhat server, what am I to do? Am I to install the api on the server and call it with my server url? e.g. suppose i host on a server with IP `20.199.399.23` , am I to call create_wallet like this: `https://20.199.399.23/api/v2/create`?